# Changing body background image with React

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image

So, I'm trying to create a React App that changes the background image of the body.  I did this by giving the body in my index.html an id of "body."  I can get this to work with changing the background COLOR just fine.  When I try to reassign the background IMAGE, though, I can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try.

This works:

```
document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

This doesn't:

```
    import explosion from "./explosion.png";

function Boom(){
document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + {explosion} +
"')";
```

Why?  I've tried writing this many different ways.

Comment: `{explosion}`  why you sending an object?, try removing the `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me :

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import img from './img.png';

export default function App(){

    useEffect(()=>{
        document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundImage = `url('${img}')`;
    })
    return <>
    <div id="body"
    style={{height:'300px'}}
    >

    </div>
    </>

}
```

or you can use inline css style :

```
import img from './img.png';

export default function App(){
    return <>
    <div id="body"
    style={{
        height:'300px',
        backgroundImage: `url('${img}')`,
    }}
    >

    </div>
    </>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the URL of the image as a string, without wrapping it in curly braces `{}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const bgUrl =
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605106250963-ffda6d2a4b32?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80";

  /*useEffect Hook allows you to perform side effects in your components. Such as fetching data, directly updating the DOM, and timers*/
  useEffect(() => {
    Boom();
  }, []);

  const Boom = () => {
    document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage = `url(${bgUrl})`;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here's a link to the working demo  [Change Background Image](https://codesandbox.io/s/change-background-image-2c66d8?file=/src/App.js:35-57)

Comment: @DennisM - It would be wonderful if you could share your bit of code. As there are numerous techniques to alter the background image of the body in reactJs.